# Como veo la informacion de este metodo en este JLABEL?

Tags: java, netbeans, interfaz, jlabel

El caso es que tengo un un provecto con dos carpetas, en una clase de una carpeta tengo el siguiente metodo:

[image: Este metodo me permite ver una lista]

Y en otra carpeta con otra clase tengo el siguiente diseño:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La clase no tiene prácticamente código mas haya del que se requiere para el diseño. En cualquier caso, como hago que sea la información de ese método en ese JLABEL?

he visto algo con seText pero como la clase esta en otra carpeta se me complica, alguna idea?

Comment: Dos cosas:
-  Si los tienes en carpetas (paquetes diferentes) deberás volver el archivo donde está el método a un archivo .JAR, es decir una libreria que puedas utilizar en tu otro paquete donde tienes el JFrame.
- Después de hacer lo primero que mencioné ya solo sería importar la libreria en tu clase JFrame y hacer el llamado.
- En el momento de hacer el llamado, no creo que puedas hacer el llamado directamente dentro del jLabel.setText("aqui") sino que deberas recibir la info en una var o array, dependiendo de como funcione tu metodo, y pasarle esa var o array al jLabel.setText()

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono!